# Get the value of cookie before express sends it to the client / Storing the cookie value in the session storage

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, passport.js

I am using [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/) and [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) to create a cookie based session. I want to store the value of cookie being sent, into the session storage. But since it is a HTTP only cookie, it cannot be accessed via javascript. I tried reading the `set-cookie` header from javascript but does not work with HTTP only cookies.

To overcome this, I was trying a way where I could send the cookie to the client but in a separate header or may be in a JSON response. But I have been unsuccessful here. Just before sending the response to the client, I tried to get the headers using `request.getHeaders()` but it does not have the cookie headers (and thus I do not get the cookie value)

Following is a snippet that uses `passportjs` to establish a session.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Is there a way I could access the cookie value with express before sending to the client?

I also tried if I could find the cookie value inside `request.session.cookie` but this object does not have the cookie value sent to the client.

Comment: *I want to store the value of cookie being sent, into the session storage* -- Can we know why do you want to do so?

Comment: I mean, it is already being done by `session-storage` itself. The `sesssion-id` is saved in the cookie and `session-payload` along with `session-id` is saved in the specifies session-storage.

Comment: @AnandUndavia I don't think I understand you. Cookies are not stored in the application level session-storage.

Comment: Yes, cookies are not saved in the session-storage. Cookies are saved in client browser. The session object is saved in the application session storage.

Comment: @AnandUndavia Could you suggest a way on how can I get the cookie just before sending to the browser?